# How to print all mysql rows

Tags: php, mysql, forms, select, authentication

```
 require('db.php');


  $query = 'SELECT username,password FROM users';

  $result = mysql_query($query, $db);

  $text = mysql_fetch_assoc($risultato);


   if($text['username'] == $_POST['user'] && $text['password'] == $_POST['pass']) {

    echo  $text['username'];;
}
else {

    echo 'NO!';
}
```

I'm a young italian developer:
This mysql select result is only the first line of the table, i'm writing the code for a login.php page.
Should i use WHERE ?How? 
I also have an id field (BIG INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT)

Comment: Seems you're only getting the first entry in the result array. Also, $text is fetching the association of a different variable? And what is $testo? Also, there are significant security issues with your current code (mysql php functions and plain text passwords, but that's ok for learning)

Comment: Start a (while) loop

Comment: There are lot of security problems with your code. mysql_* is depricated. Use mysqli_* or PDF instead. This is said, you need to loop over `$text` using while ($text = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    // do your job
}

Comment: You're using the wrong variable in `$text = mysql_fetch_assoc($risultato);` where it should be `$text = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` - However, you may be best to use `mysql_num_rows()` for your query when it comes to match rows against usernames and passwords.

Comment: Actually, you should check out http://daveismyname.com/login-and-registration-system-with-php-bp - It uses PDO with prepared statements and `password_hash()` which are a lot (molto) safer.

Answer (score 1):

[`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) fetches the next row from the result set as long as there is one, or `false` if the result set is exhausted - so you can loop over it:

```
while ($text = mysql_fetch_assoc($risultato)) {
    if($text['username'] == $_POST['user'] && $testo['password'] == $_POST['pass']) {
        echo  $text['username'] . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

---

- Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) while using a deprecated MySQL library.
  Use [**`mysqli` prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

**Regarding password storage**

It seems you are storing passwords in plain text. If this is the case, it is highly discouraged.

It it is recommend for you to use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: -1 Don't provide code that allows people to write insecure web applications.

Comment: @siride I've modified the answer to suit and in more ways than one ;)